# Are their any guarantees made as to which body is bodyA and bodyB when didBegin(_:) is called?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When a contact occurs in an `SKScene` that invokes `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`, it is necessary to determine which `SKPhysicsBody` is `contact.bodyA` and which is `contact.bodyB`. However, I have been unsuccessful in discovering how this is set before the function is called. This is resulting in unsuccessful downcasts (e.g. `(contact.bodyA.node! as! MySpriteNode)` that cause the application to crash.

My theories for a pattern have involved it being determined by the ordering of the `SKNode` objects in the application's node tree or their order in the scene's `self.childen`, but this has proven to be incorrect. Sometimes a node that is later in `self.children` than `bodyB.node` ends up as `bodyA.node`. I have also found no pattern involving the values of `categoryBitMask` or `contactTestBitMask`.

Apple's most recent documentation seems to be silent on the issue. Are their any guarantees made as to which body will be which? I don't want to have to write identical code for each pairing orientation, and I'm sure that this isn't the method that is intended.

Comment: Take a look at documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision#t=201610101513095635661

Answer (score 2):

There are no guarantees to the order of the bodies inside of the contact variable, but we can guarantee our order inside of the method.

Let's say you have 3 entities with SKPhysicsBody

```
class Hero: SKSpriteNode { }
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode { }
class Gun: SKSpriteNode { }
```

You could organize the didBegin(_ contact:) method like this

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        guard
            let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node,
            let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node
            else { return }

        switch (nodeA, nodeB) {

        case let (hero, enemy) as (Hero, Enemy): break
        case let (enemy, hero) as (Enemy, Hero): break

        case let (hero, gun) as (Hero, Gun): break
        case let (gun, hero) as (Gun, Hero): break

        case let (enemy, gun) as (Enemy, Gun): break
        case let (gun, enemy) as (Gun, Enemy): break

        default: fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```